# Excel number formatting is wrong

Tags: excel

I have a lot of numbers and in Excel these numbers are displayed in a wrong way. Excel adds a lot of dots in between the numbers.

In the program NUMBERS it is display correctly. I need to manipulate this data in Excel. Can anyone help me how to set the numbers in Excel correctly?

Incorrect dots in between the numbers in Excel:

[image]

Correct way the numbers are presented in NUMBERS:

[image]

Comment: How did you get these numbers in Excel in the first place?

Comment: Are you using the **dot** in NUMBERS as a decimal separator ??

Comment: @GSerg I got the numbers as they are shown here. Unfortunately, I do not know how these numbers where generated.

Comment: in NUMBERS I did not change any format settings, I am using the default settings (Europe)

Comment: It appears that Excel is using the dot as the thousands separator, and Numbers is using the dot as the decimal point.  The difference is **not** a matter of formatting -- the difference is the actual value stored in the cell.

Comment: there does not seem to be a pattern to the data set, such as say each measurement is to the nth place, so it is likely impossible to remove decimals and place decimal where you want it. likely an issue in import. may want to see if other users of Numbers have run into this.

Comment: @learnAsWeGo - why did you delete your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64082543/8112776)?  It looks to me like there's a good chance it's the solution, and not if to this problem, then possibly to others with similar symptoms.

Comment: @ashleedawg only pattern I can see is:  if a column has three digits then decimal, the other column does as well. same is true for four digits. would look into it a bit more, but the data is present as .img rather than text. you are right though, given the title of the post, quite possible someone comes here looking for answer i provided. undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your options, more exactly the "advanced" ones, as indicated in the following screenshot, apparently both boxes have the same separator value for decimals and for the thousands (sorry for the Dutch, that's just the language of my Excel installation):

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use Find and Replace function to replace all . with blank.

[image]

Then change format Number with Use 1000 Separator property marked true.

[image]